# Decode JavaScript encoded content

Tags: javascript, php

I'm writing a web crawler tool to collect the email addresses. After downloading the HTML content and parsing it using `DomCrawler`, I get this node value:

```
<!--
document.write("<a rel='nofollow' href='mailto:&#104;&#105;&#101;&#117;&#98;&#100;&#115;&#104;&#97;&#112;&#112;&#121;&#64;&#103;&#109;&#97;&#105;&#108;&#46;&#99;&#111;&#109;'>&#104;&#105;&#101;&#117;&#98;&#100;&#115;&#104;&#97;&#112;&#112;&#121;&#64;&#103;&#109;&#97;&#105;&#108;&#46;&#99;&#111;&#109;");
//-->This email address has been protected. You need to enable JavaScript to view the content.
```

How could I decode it?

Answer (score 2):

The value is just html encoded values of the characters from the original string so in PHP you can use html_entity_decode to get the original text.

```
$returnValue = html_entity_decode('mailto:&#104;&#105;&#101;&#117;&#98;&#100;&#115;&#104;&#97;&#112;&#112;&#121;&#64;&#103;&#109;&#97;&#105;&#108;&#46;&#99;&#111;&#109;'>&#104;&#105;&#101;&#117;&#98;&#100;&#115;&#104;&#97;&#112;&#112;&#121;&#64;&#103;&#109;&#97;&#105;&#108;&#46;&#99;&#111;&#109;', ENT_COMPAT);
```

See: https://www.functions-online.com/html_entity_decode.html